# Linux—command to delete images from pdf

Tags: pdf, images

I have a pdf, which is huge since it was exported from photoshop and I hardly can open it. It contains text, I like to copy/paste.

Is there command to remove all images from a pdf and save the result as new file?

Btw. I have already tried `pdftotext`, but the resulting file is messed up, line broken down to maximum 10 characters, all lot of whitespace and so forth.

**UPDATE**

I found a nice thread [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477663/how-to-remove-images-from-a-pdf-file) but none of the solutions worked, so I guess the »photoshop pdf« is really messed up…

Comment: [A suggestion by luksfuks](https://old.reddit.com/r/pdf/comments/tgfd6s/how_to_delete_some_images_form_a_pdf_with_mutool/i1c7ymg/) is to corrupt the object references with sed and then remove the invalid stuff with qpdf/mutool. However, in many cases it might be possible to simply use qpdf to remove specific objects. See for instance in https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html `qpdf --show-pages --with-images` to list the images, then it's easier to figure out how to remove specific objects.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the text you want to extract it might be better to run [pdf2txt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pdf2txt.1.html) on it.

Comment: that better, but there still some strange things in it, I guess some escape sequences like: `Di(cid:249)erent` in it… But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Giving credit to the solution posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/787844/161810), the following is going to remove the images and give you the exact result you need:

```
gs -o no-images.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFILTERIMAGE original.pdf
```

`Ghostscript` is readily available in virtually any Linux distribution